# emacs regex help

Tags: regex, emacs

Okay, this should be super easy, I must be doing something dumb.

I've got this:

```
double foo3;
```

I want to replace it with:

```
archiver & BOOST_SERIALIZATION(foo3);
```

I do this:

```
M-x query-replace-regxp RET double \(a-z0-9+\) RET archiver & BOOST_SERIALIZATION(\1)
```

Emacs says 0 matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mist the List Operator:

```
double \([a-z0-9]+\)
```

Comment: Doh. Thanks. I need more coffee.